# How does lodash's modular build work? Or any commonjs modular build work?

Tags: npm, lodash, commonjs

It's my understanding that I can

`npm install lodash`

but then call

`require('lodash/collections/each')`

and only get that single function without the overhead of loading all of lodash.

How does that work? I can't quite figure it out looking at lodash's package.json.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that this is just the normal way you'd require something using node/commonjs syntax.

Imagine if lodash were just another folder on your desktop, you could require the function in this way:

```
var each = require('./Desktop/lodash/collections/each')
```

The trick lodash is doing is that they have another file marked as the 'entry' in their package.json that grabs all the different functions from their subdirectories and adds them to the exported lodash object:

```
//index.js
module.exports = {
   each: require('./collections/each'),
   keys: require('./object/keys')
   ...etc
}
```

Which is why you can also say:

```
var each = require('lodash').each
```